# textboxfor does not work in templates in twitterbootstrap.mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [TwitterBootstrapMvc](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570762/TwitterBootstrapMvc)

trying to use editortemplates and specify the details in the templates

the template looks like below:

```
@model Int64?
@Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
```

after debugging the code for this project:

```
    public BootstrapTextBox TextBoxFor<TValue>(Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        return new BootstrapTextBox(Html, ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression), ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, Html.ViewData));
    }


    public BootstrapTextBox(HtmlHelper html, string htmlFieldName, ModelMetadata metadata)
        : base(html, htmlFieldName, metadata)
    {

    }
```

the call to this method BootstrapTextBox receives empty field name and no metadata. tried to debug but could not find any place to fix this....

any idea on how to take it further??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for TwitterBootstrapMvc is available on [github](https://github.com/DmitryEfimenko/TwitterBootstrapMvc). It would be great if you figured out why it's not working as expected and submitted a pull request!

Comment: i know the problem... but wasnt able to solve it, hence still not using editor templates... sorry cant help you on this

Comment: It's fixed in the latest version.